# need of webpack in server end

Tags: webpack, babeljs, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am developing a full stack application using
node, apollo-server 2, mongoDB - **back end**
react, apollo-boost - **front end**

also implementing babel webpack bundling in front end and in many of the apollo server examples i can see they also used webpack for back end also..

So I confused with this thing why we need to use webpack for apollo-server end.. I hope in server the code size is not bigger..

please anyone help with this to clear my confusion and redirect me if there is any links.

Thanks

Comment: they used because they probably wanted to use non-native es6 syntax/features on node and be able to run on nodejs itself

Comment: ok, but this is the only reason for using web pack in the server end?

Comment: yes, no other reason.